# Schema validation with `zodResolver` in `react-hook-form` doesn't work correctly in `vitest` tests

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, vitest, zod

The schema validation works fine in the runtime environment and passes the unit tests, but the tests fail when integration testing with the `react-hook-form` library.

Here is the schema i created with `zod`.

```
import { z } from "zod";

const errorMessages = {
  required: "This field is required.",
  email: "Invalid email.",
  passwordMinLength: "Password must be at least 8 characters.",
  passwordMaxLength: "Password must be no more than 16 characters.",
  passwordPattern:
    "Password must contain a combination of lowercase letters, numbers, and uppercase letters.",
};

const {
  required,
  email,
  passwordMinLength,
  passwordMaxLength,
  passwordPattern,
} = errorMessages;

export const exampleLoginSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().min(1, { message: required }).email({ message: email }),
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(8, { message: passwordMinLength })
    .max(16, { message: passwordMaxLength })
    .regex(/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,16}$/, {
      message: passwordPattern,
    }),
});

export type ExampleLoginSchema = z.infer<typeof exampleLoginSchema>;
```

And this is my test data.

```
export const testData = {
  validEmail: "test@example.com",
  validPassword: "Test1234!",
  invalidEmail: "invalidemail",
  invalidPassword: "Test12345678",
  emptyString: "",
};
```

Below is the unit test code for that schema, and it passes all test cases.

```
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import { exampleLoginSchema } from "../schema/example";
import { testData } from "../testData";

describe("Example login schema", () => {
  test("Should pass with valid data", () => {
    const validData = {
      email: testData.validEmail,
      password: testData.validPassword,
    };

    const validationResult = exampleLoginSchema.safeParse(validData);
    expect(validationResult.success).toBe(true);
  });

  test("Should fail when required fields are missing", () => {
    const invalidData = {
      email: testData.emptyString,
      password: testData.emptyString,
    };

    const validationResult = exampleLoginSchema.safeParse(invalidData);
    expect(validationResult.success).toBe(false);
  });

  test("Should fail when the email is invalid", () => {
    const invalidData = {
      email: testData.invalidEmail,
      password: testData.validPassword,
    };

    const validationResult = exampleLoginSchema.safeParse(invalidData);
    expect(validationResult.success).toBe(false);
  });

  test("Should fail when the password is invalid", () => {
    const invalidData = {
      email: testData.validEmail,
      password: testData.invalidPassword,
    };

    const validationResult = exampleLoginSchema.safeParse(invalidData);
    expect(validationResult.success).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

However, in the following integration tests, the "Should call onSubmit function when the input is correct" and the "Should not call onSubmit function when there is an invalid input" test case fail. Where is the problem?

```
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { describe, test, vi } from "vitest";
import { exampleLoginSchema } from "../schema/example";
import { Form } from "./Form";
import { testData } from "../testData";

const mockSubmit = vi.fn((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

describe("Form Component", () => {
  test("Should render Form component correctly", () => {
    render(
      <Form onSubmit={mockSubmit} testId="form">
        <Form.Input type="text" name="test" />
      </Form>
    );

    const formElement = screen.getByTestId("form");
    expect(formElement).to.be.ok;

    const inputElement = screen.getAllByLabelText("test");
    expect(inputElement).to.be.ok;
  });

  test("Should render feedback messages for invalid inputs", async () => {
    render(
      <Form onSubmit={mockSubmit} resolver={zodResolver(exampleLoginSchema)}>
        <Form.Input type="email" name="email" />
        <Form.Input type="password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit">click me</button>
      </Form>
    );

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));

    expect(await screen.findAllByRole("alert")).toHaveLength(2);

    expect(mockSubmit).not.toBeCalled();
  });

  test("Should call onSubmit function when the input is correct", () => {
    render(
      <Form onSubmit={mockSubmit} resolver={zodResolver(exampleLoginSchema)}>
        <Form.Input type="email" name="email" />
        <Form.Input type="password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit">click me</button>
      </Form>
    );

    fireEvent.input(screen.getByLabelText("email"), {
      target: {
        value: testData.validEmail,
      },
    });

    fireEvent.input(screen.getByLabelText("password"), {
      target: {
        value: testData.validPassword,
      },
    });

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));

    expect(mockSubmit).toBeCalled();
  });

  test("Should not call onSubmit function when there is an invalid input", async () => {
    render(
      <Form onSubmit={mockSubmit} resolver={zodResolver(exampleLoginSchema)}>
        <Form.Input type="email" name="email" />
        <Form.Input type="password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit">click me</button>
      </Form>
    );

    fireEvent.input(screen.getByLabelText("email"), {
      target: {
        value: testData.invalidEmail,
      },
    });

    fireEvent.input(screen.getByLabelText("password"), {
      target: {
        value: testData.invalidPassword,
      },
    });

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));

    expect(mockSubmit).not.toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Here's the individual component code

`Form`

```
import React from "react";
import type { ReactNode } from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import type { FieldValues, SubmitHandler, UseFormProps } from "react-hook-form";

import { Input } from "./Input";

type BasicTestProps = {
  testId?: string;
};

type Children = {
  children?: ReactNode;
};

type ExternalFormProps<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = {
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TFieldValues>;
};

type CustomFormProps<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> =
  UseFormProps<TFieldValues> &
    ExternalFormProps<TFieldValues> &
    BasicTestProps &
    Children;

const FormBase = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues>({
  children,
  onSubmit,
  ...props
}: CustomFormProps<TFieldValues>) => {
  const methods = useForm<TFieldValues>(props);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form
        onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        data-testid={props.testId}
      >
        {children}
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

const Form = Object.assign(FormBase, { Input });

export { Form };
```

`Input`

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

type InputProps = Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, "name"> & {
  name: string;
};

const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
  const { type, name } = props;
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
      <input type={type} id={name} {...register(name)} />
      {errors[name] && <p role="alert">{errors[name]?.message?.toString()}</p>}
    </>
  );
};

export { Input };
```

If you want to see all the code I implemented, here's the link

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/gomgun-lab/bug-report/draft/vigorous-galileo?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clifmh65z000b356qzwnzsmgu%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clifmh65z000d356qfbiowpxd%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clifmh65z000b356qzwnzsmgu%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clifmh65y000a356qc6tybfr5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Ftsconfig.json%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clifmh65z000b356qzwnzsmgu%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clifmh65y000a356qc6tybfr5%2522%257D%252C%2522clifmh65z000d356qfbiowpxd%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clifmh65z000c356qgw2qvvi8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clifmh65z000d356qfbiowpxd%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clifmh65z000c356qgw2qvvi8%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out by any chance?  I've run into the same problem.